# getting the previous month on the last day of the month.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that i run each day at 3 AM to give me the sales of the current month.

The problem arise at the last day of each month. Because the month has already flipped. 
So when i run at 1st November 3 AM it gives 0. Whereas it should give me the sales of October.
Here is the query.

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS added_orders
FROM `order`
WHERE date_added > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -31 DAY)
AND order_status_id != 0
AND MONTH(date_added)= MONTH(curdate())
```

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS added_orders FROM `order` 
where date_added > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -31 DAY) AND order_status_id != 0  
AND MONTH(date_added)= MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
```

i changed MONTH(date_added)= MONTH(curdate()), so that it takes the month of the previous day

Answer (score 0):

try this !!

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS added_orders
    FROM `order`
    WHERE date_added > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -31 DAY)
    AND order_status_id != 0
    AND MONTH(date_added)=Convert(datetime, DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate())));
```

Comment: or add this to MONTH(date_added)=DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate()));

Answer (score -1):

You could use the same month as whatever is 31 days ago...

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS added_orders
FROM `order`
WHERE date_added > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -31 DAY)
AND order_status_id != 0
AND MONTH(date_added)= MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -31 DAY))
```

Comment: Not really. If you were looking for a rolling 31 days like the OP is here, on the fifteenth of November, you wouldn't use October as the month there.

Comment: OP isn't looking for a rolling period. The problem is that he runs his query at 3AM so on the last day of the month when the query is run `MONTH(curdate())` will return the next month.

Comment: `I have a query that i run each day at 3 AM`: thus my statement is still 100% true. The OP runs the query every day. So, on the fifteenth of November, your query returns October, that would be wrong. Each day the query is looking over the past 31 days based on the date it's run.

Comment: Granted in the scenario you have posed the query will return the previous month, which is incorrect. However your statement of `If you were looking for a rolling 31 days like the OP is here` makes it 100% false as this is not what the OP is looking for. :)